How can I make form of a book like this?
Form here I see a document. The form of document is different from a normal document.

Each paragraph is numbered

I tried with normal form of LaTeX
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\part{}
\chapter{GOD'S PLAN OF LOVE FOR HUMANITY}
\section{GOD'S LIBERATING ACTION
IN THE HISTORY OF ISRAEL}
\subsection{ God's gratuitous presence}
\url{https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/pontifical_councils/justpeace/documents/rc_pc_justpeace_doc_20060526_compendio-dott-soc_en.html#At%20the%20dawn%20of%20the%20Third%20Millennium
}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item  The Church moves further into the Third Millennium of the Christian era as a pilgrim people, guided by Christ, the “great Shepherd” (Heb 13:20). He is the “Holy Door” (cf. Jn 10:9) through which we passed during the Great Jubilee of the year 2000[1]. Jesus Christ is the Way, the Truth and the Life (cf. Jn 14:6): contemplating the Lord's face, we confirm our faith and our hope in him, the one Saviour and goal of history.

\item The Church continues to speak to all people and all nations, for it is only in the name of Christ that salvation is given to men and women. Salvation, which the Lord Jesus obtained “at a price” (1 Cor 6:20; cf. 1 Pet 1:18-19), is achieved in the new life that awaits the righteous after death, but it also permeates this world in the realities of the economy and labour, of technology and communications, of society and politics, of the international community and the relations among cultures and peoples. “Jesus came to bring integral salvation, one which embraces the whole person and all mankind, and opens up the wondrous prospect of divine filiation”[2].

\item. At the dawn of this Third Millennium, the Church does not tire of proclaiming the Gospel that brings salvation and genuine freedom also to temporal realities. She is mindful of the solemn exhortation given by Saint Paul to his disciple Timothy: “Preach the word, be urgent in season and out of season, convince, rebuke, and exhort, be unfailing in patience and in teaching. For the time is coming when people will not endure sound teaching, but having itching ears they will accumulate for themselves teachers to suit their own likings, and will turn away from listening to the truth and wander into myths. As for you, always be steady, endure suffering, do the work of an evangelist, fulfil your ministry” (2 Tim 4:2-5).

\item To the people of our time, her travelling companions, the Church also offers her social doctrine. In fact, when the Church “fulfils her mission of proclaiming the Gospel, she bears witness to man, in the name of Christ, to his dignity and his vocation to the communion of persons. She teaches him the demands of justice and peace in conformity with divine wisdom”[3]. This doctrine has its own profound unity, which flows from Faith in a whole and complete salvation, from Hope in a fullness of justice, and from Love which makes all mankind truly brothers and sisters in Christ: it is the expression of God's love for the world, which he so loved “that he gave his only Son” (Jn 3:16). The new law of love embraces the entire human family and knows no limits, since the proclamation of the salvation wrought by Christ extends “to the ends of the earth” (Acts 1:8).
 
\end{enumerate}
 
\end{document}

Current:

How can I get the form from here

Perhaps I did not understand you question correctly, but what do you want to achieve? The paragraphs only being numbered? Or the all stylistic aspect of the attachment, including the fonts used and the title formation.

You will first need to redefine \thechapter ,\thesection and possibly \theparagraph.  If you use enumerate instead of \paragraph, you can use the enumitem package to change the item format.

If you use titlesec, you should also use it in your code. See its manual https://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec

About number paragraph, you can see here

If I understood correctly, you want to change the format of your current document to a similar style as the attachment you posted. To achieve this, and following the comments suggested by @John Kormylo, you need to redefine some commands such as \thechapter and \thesection. Additionally, you need to format the titles of each section using the \titleformat command.
I can provide you with a MWE of the changes. Be aware that I did not change the fonts or colors of the document to make them similar to the attachment.
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2 cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fmtcount} % For the text to number conversion.

\newcounter{para}
\newcommand*{\numberedparagraph}{%
  \refstepcounter{para}\textbf{\thepara.}\space
}

\makeatletter

\preto\section{\everypar{}}
\preto\subsection{\everypar{}}
\preto\subsubsection{\everypar{}}

\renewcommand{\@afterheading}{%
  \@nobreaktrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@nobreak
      \@nobreakfalse
      \clubpenalty\@M
      \if@afterindent
      \else
        {\setbox\z@\lastbox}%
      \fi
    \else
      \clubpenalty\@clubpenalty
      \everypar{\numberedparagraph}%
    \fi
    \numberedparagraph
  }%
}


\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\NUMBERstringnum{1}}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}.}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\centering\large}{CHAPTER \thechapter}{0pt}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\centering\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5em}{}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\raggedright\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}[]

\begin{document}
\part{}
\chapter{GOD'S PLAN OF LOVE FOR HUMANITY}
\section{GOD'S LIBERATING ACTION \\ IN THE HISTORY OF ISRAEL}
\subsection{God's gratuitous presence}

Every authentic religious experience, in all cultural traditions, leads to an intuition of the Mystery that, not infrequently, is able to recognize some aspect of God's face. On the one hand, God is seen as the origin of what exists, as the presence that guarantees to men and women organized in a society.

Every authentic religious experience, in all cultural traditions, leads to an intuition of the Mystery that, not infrequently, is able to recognize some aspect of God's face. On the one hand, God is seen as the origin of what exists, as the presence that guarantees to men and women organized in a society.

Every authentic religious experience, in all cultural traditions, leads to an intuition of the Mystery that, not infrequently, is able to recognize some aspect of God's face. On the one hand, God is seen as the origin of what exists, as the presence that guarantees to men and women organized in a society.

\subsection{God's gratuitous presence}

The gratuitousness of this historically efficacious divine action is constantly accompanied by the commitment to the covenant, proposed by God and accepted by Israel.

Against the background of universal religious experience, in which humanity shares in different ways, God's progressive revelation of himself to the people of Israel.

The gratuitousness of this historically efficacious divine action is constantly accompanied by the commitment to the covenant, proposed by God and accepted by Israel.

\end{document}

It results in the following:

This solution alters the format of the chapter, section, and subsection titles. It also creates a counter for each paragraph. It's not an elegant solution, especially for the paragraph numeration, but it is the one I can provide at this time. I will look for a more automated solution for the paragraph counter in the future and can edit it then if I find one.
EDIT: Because to this (incredible) blog, I was able to provide a automatically solution for the paragraphs numbering! This solution uses a normal counter and renews the command \@afterheading to make it fully automatically. Please check the code provided and the result screenshot of the MWE.
Hope it helps.

I accepted your answer, but please try \tableofcontents.

Again, in your question you didn't specify what you exactly wanted to achieve. But there's no problem, I'll try to do it anyways :-)
Just make sure that the next time you ask a question, try to correctly specify what you want to achieve.

Might something as simple as this suffice?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\newcounter{paragraphcounter}
\newcommand{\numberparagraph}{\stepcounter{paragraphcounter}\noindent\textbf{\arabic{paragraphcounter}}.\ }

\begin{document}
    
    \numberparagraph This is the first paragraph. 
    
    \numberparagraph This is the second paragraph. 
    
    \numberparagraph This is the third paragraph. 
    
    This is without the paragraph counter.
    
    \numberparagraph And with again.
    
    \setcounter{paragraphcounter}{0} %And this resets the counter.
    
    \numberparagraph This is a reset paragraph counter.
    
\end{document}


That's a good solution, and resembles the one that I provided. Good job! Although I don't know if the OP wanted a full redefinition of the style of the document, but I did it anyways.

Yours is much better and more detailed than mine!
